# Encontrar el índice de elemento en un array

Tags: javascript, array, test

Estoy tratando de resolver un test pero no me está pasando.

La consigna es la siguiente:

> Escribi una función encontraIndex en el prototipo de Arrays,
> que recibe un elemento.
>
> La function tiene que devolver el indice (index) del primer elemento que coincida con el pasado como parametro dentro del array.
>
> Si el elemento se repite dentro del Array, este devuelve el indice del Primer elemento.
>
> Si no existe ese elemento la funcion debe devolver -1
>
> NO USAR LA FUNCION indexOf DE LOS ARREGLOS.

Y un ejemplo del funcionamiento:

```javascript
var numeros = [5, 6, 4, 65, 8, 4]
numeros.encontraIndex(4) // debe devolver 2
numeros.encontraIndex(23) // debe devolver -1
```

¿Alguna idea para resolverlo? Se agradece mucho.

Comment: puedes hacerlo con el metodo [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf)

Comment: Me dice que no puedo usarlo :(

Comment: si quieres una respuesta mas completa debes agregar lo que as intentando hasta ahora! ya que podemos ayudarte a solucionarlo mas no hacerte la tarea!

Comment: findIndex() vale? que metodos viste hasta ahora?

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente se recomienda [no alterar el prototipo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859828/javascript-what-dangers-are-in-extending-array-prototype), aunque de ser necesario debe hacerse bajo propio riesgo.

De la documentación tenemos que:

> El método indexOf() retorna el primer índice en el que se puede encontrar un elemento dado en el array, ó retorna -1 si el elemento no esta presente.

En caso de no encontrar el valor, esta implementación devuelve -1, como la función [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf) original.

**Edit:** agregué algunas mejoras para hacer la implementación similar a la función original, ahora puedes especificar desde dónde quieres comenzar la búsqueda (`0`, inicio por defecto).

```js
Array.prototype.encontrarIndice = function (valor, desde = 0) {
  if (desde > this.length - 1) {
    throw new Error('Indice fuera de rango');
  }
  for (let index = desde; index < this.length; index++) {
    if (this[index] === valor) {
      return index
    }
  }
  return -1
}

const numeros = [5, 6, 4, 65, 8, 4];
//    indices = [0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5]

// Primer 4
console.log(numeros.encontrarIndice(4));
// Segundo 4
console.log(numeros.encontrarIndice(4, 5));
// No existe en el array
console.log(numeros.encontrarIndice(10));
// Error, fuera de rango
console.log(numeros.encontrarIndice(4, 6));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 Array.prototype.encontraIndex= function(numero){
    var pos=[];
    for(var i =0; i<this.length; i++){
      if(numero === this[i]){
        pos.push(i)
      }
    }
    if(pos.length>0){
       return pos[0];
    }
    return -1
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas formas de resolver esto, creo que falta un poco de contexto de como quieres resolverlo.

Como comentaron antes, el indexOf es la mejor solución pero también puedes hacerlo de la forma lenta

```js
const numbers = [5, 6, 4, 65, 8, 4]

function findIndexFor(array, value){
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] === value){ 
      return i;
    }
  }
};

function findIndexForEach(array, value ){
  let position = -1;
  array.forEach((val, index) => {
    if(val === value && position === -1) {
      position = index;
    }
  });
  return position;
};

console.log(findIndexFor(numbers, 4));
console.log(findIndexForEach(numbers, 4));
```

Aquí te dejo 2 posibles soluciones, espero que te sirva y ojala publiquen mas opciones.

EDIT 1: Olvide poner el link de referencia del foreach
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

```
function index() {
  // Escribi una función encontraIndex en el prototipo de Arrays,
  // que recibe un elemento.
  // La function tiene que devolver el indice (index) del primer elemento que coincida con el pasado como parametro dentro del array.
  // Si el elemento se repite dentro del Array, este devuelve el indice del Primer elemento.
  // Si no existe ese elemento la funcion debe devolver -1
  // NO USAR LA FUNCION indexOf DE LOS ARREGLOS.
  // ej:
  // var numeros = [5, 6, 4, 65, 8, 4]
  // numeros.encontraIndex(4) debe devolver 2.
  // ya que el numero 4 se encuentra en la posicion 2 dentro del array.
  // numeros.encontraIndex(23) debe devolver -1 ya que ese elemento no existe en ese array.
  // this.findIndex((e) => e === elemento)
  // Tu código aca:

  // Creamos el método (función) "encontraIndex" en el proto de Array
  // La función recibe un elemento como parámetro
  Array.prototype.encontraIndex = function (elemento) {
  // Iteramos sobre el Array
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
  // Comprobamos si el valor del índice en donde estoy parado en la iteración es igual al elemento
      if (this[i] === elemento)
  // si es verdad, retornamos el índice en el que se encuentra el valor igual al elemento
      return i;
    }
  // Si salimos del bucle es porque no hemos encontrado lo que buscamos
  // Retornamos -1
      return -1;
  }
};
```

Comment: Puede que el código esté correcto, pero sin una explicación de cómo funciona y de los detalles del lenguaje ("===" vs "=="), el OP no aprendió nada.

Comment: @CandidMoe Gracias por la corrección, ya esta editado. Espero me de a entender.

Answer (score 0):

Lo unico que hay que hacer es usar this como el array que después en el test se intercambiará (por así decirlo);
A lo que me refiero es que uses el this como si fuera un array, usalo para iterar con un for.

```
for(let i = 0; i<this.length;i++){
  if(this[i] === element)return i
}
return -1
```

}

}